# How do I implement a queue system into my Discord Music Bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, *, url = None):
  if ctx.author.voice is None:
      msg = await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
      await msg.delete(delay = 3)
  voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
  if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
  else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

  search_keyword = url
  if not ("youtube.com/watch?" in search_keyword):
    search_keyword = search_keyword.replace(" ", "+")
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={search_keyword}")
    video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
    url = str(f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_ids[0]}")
  
  ctx.voice_client.stop()
  FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
  YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
  vc = ctx.voice_client

  with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    title = info.get('title', None)
    length = info['duration']
    url2 = info["formats"][0]["url"]
    source = await discord. FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
    vc.play(source)
  
  embed = discord.Embed(title = "Currently Playing", colour = discord.Colour.blue())
  embed.add_field(name = "Song", value = title, inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name = "Length", value = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = length)), inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name = "Link", value = url, inline = False)
  msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await msg.add_reaction("\u23F8")
  await msg.add_reaction("\u25B6")
  await msg.add_reaction("\u23F9")
  while True:
    try:
      reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: user.id == ctx.author.id and reaction.message.id == msg.id and reaction.emoji in ["\u23F8", "\u25B6", "\u23F9"], timeout = length)
    
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      return await msg.clear_reactions()
        
    async def process():
      if reaction.emoji == "\u23F8":
        await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)
        ctx.voice_client.pause()
      elif reaction.emoji == "\u25B6":
        await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)
        ctx.voice_client.resume()
      elif reaction.emoji == "\u23F9":
        await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)
        ctx.voice_client.stop()

    asyncio.create_task(process())
```

Here's the code for my play command. Right now if the command is invoked while a song is playing, then that song stops and the newly requested one begins, this is because of the  `ctx.voice_client.stop()` before the song is downloaded. However, I'm trying to implement a queue system where if the command is invoked while another song is playing it will be added to queue, and songs in the queue will be played right after the current song ends. Currently my idea of how to do this would be to replace the `ctx.voice_client.stop()` with an if statement that checks the status of the bot, if it is currently playing or not, and either appends it it to a global list variable containing the current queue or plays the song. But I am clueless on how to make it play the queue one after another and implement a skip command. Another complicated part would be to implement the skip command into a reaction similar to how I've implemented the pause and play commands. I don't now if my idea will work, so any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to creat a empty queue outside your command

`queues = {}`

and a funtion to check if there's a song in queues it will play that song

```
#check queue
queues = {}
def check_queue(ctx, id):
  if queues[id] !={}:
    voice = ctx.guild.voice_client
    source = queues[id].pop(0)
    voice.play(source, after=lambda x=0: check_queue(ctx, ctx.message.guild.id))
```

and inside play command create a funtion to add the next song to queue if a song is already being played and add the check queue funtion

```
  if voice.is_playing():
    guild_id = ctx.message.guild.id
    if guild_id in queues:
      queues[guild_id].append(source)
    else:
      queues[guild_id] = [source]
  else:
    vc.play(source, after=lambda x=0: check_queue(ctx, ctx.message.guild.id))
```

You can check out my code here if u need more help [Need help Discord bot queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69734318/17241497)