# Adding a queue command to discord.py music bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm looking for a way to add the following to my music bot:

- A queue function, allowing songs to be inputted while another plays. This would then go through the play function after the first song ends
- Being able to display this queue
- Removing songs from/changing positions of the songs in the queue

How would I go about doing this? Below is my code.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
from discord.utils import get

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has successfully connected to Discord!')

@bot.command(aliases=['p'])
async def play(ctx, url: str = None):
  YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio/best', 'noplaylist':'True'}
  FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
  voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
  try:
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
  except AttributeError:
    await ctx.send('Bruh, join a voice channel')
    return None
  if not voice:
    await channel.connect()
    await ctx.send("Music/Audio will begin shortly, unless no URL provided.")
  voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
  with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
          info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
          I_URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
          source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(I_URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
          voice.play(source)
          voice.is_playing()
  await ctx.send("Playing audio.")
          
@bot.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
      voice.pause()
      await ctx.send("Audio is paused.")
    if voice.is_not_playing():
      await ctx.send("Currently no audio is playing.")

@bot.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_paused():
      voice.resume()
      await ctx.send("Resumed audio.")
    if voice.is_not_paused():
      await ctx.send("The audio is not paused.")

@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    voice.stop()
    await ctx.send("Stopped playback.")

@bot.command(aliases=['l'])  
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    await voice.disconnect()
    await ctx.send("Left voice channel.")

keep_alive()
bot.run(TOKEN
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This site is normally used for specific code bugs, or errors, that you might encounter, or need to solve, so don't fret if this question is closed down. For adding a queue, you probably want to store a list of songs, and iterate through them (for loop or iter.next()). A queue isn't super important for permanent storage, but if you want to keep it safe, look into the json module, which, when combined with the open() function, can allow you to write a dictionary to a file on the hard drive, for permanent storage.

Comment: Lol your bot gonna get taken down for using YTDL. All the best

Comment: The bot is in use in one personal server for me and my friends.

Comment: `queue` has to be as `global` list - this way all functions will have access to queue

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create an empty queue outside your command

`queues = {}`

and a function to check if there's a song in queues it will play that song

```
#check queue
queues = {}
def check_queue(ctx, id):
  if queues[id] !={}:
    voice = ctx.guild.voice_client
    source = queues[id].pop(0)
    voice.play(source, after=lambda x=0: check_queue(ctx, ctx.message.guild.id))
```

and inside the play command create a function to add the next song to queue if a song is already being played and add the check queue function

```
  if voice.is_playing():
    guild_id = ctx.message.guild.id
    if guild_id in queues:
      queues[guild_id].append(source)
    else:
      queues[guild_id] = [source]
  else:
    voice.play(source, after=lambda x=0: check_queue(ctx, ctx.message.guild.id))
```

This way is to create a queue and play the next only and still cant display or change the queue
[Need help Discord bot queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69734318/17241497)